# Acess call history using CallHistory.framework in iOS 11

Tags: ios11

Is there any way to access call history in iOS 11 using Privateframework. I don't want to upload in appstore.

Thanks

Comment: [may be this is what you are looking for](https://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/)

Comment: @FahimParkar above link is not working for iOS 11

Comment: you can search over internet for that...